# error CNDL0027 : The File/@Name attribute's value, is not a valid 8.3-compliant name

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.7, wix3.8

When I am running the windows installer build using WIX 2.0 tool set i am getting the below error.

error CNDL0027 : The File/@Name attribute's value, is not a valid. Legal names contain no more than 8 characters followed by an optional extension
of no more than 3 characters.  Any character except for the follow may be used: \ ? | > < : / * " + , ; = [ ] (space).

I am suspecting that it is due to the old version because i am using windows 10 32 bit environment.

So do i need to migrate the code and use WIX 3.0 version to resolve this error?

Regards,
Prakash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***WiX 2***: I would definitely migrate any WiX 2.0 sources to WiX 3 or WiX 4. I use WiX 3 only. I think you can solve this particular problem by putting your WiX source on a diet - rather than delve too deep in the actual subject matter / problem. Dealing with 8.3 file names is just a waste of time if you ask me. Avoid if you can. I feel sorry for developers who have to deal with all this old, legacy stuff in Windows.

***Simplify WiX Markup***: In other words I think this problem can be "removed rather than fixed". So bear with me: I like to slim my WiX source files down to the bare necessities and allow as many fields as possible to be auto-magically added by the compiler (**`candle.exe`**) and linker (**`light.exe`**). This is possible to do because a lot of fields are just "boilerplate" or redundant and will always "change together". They might as well be auto-generated.

Here is a quick description of how you can remove superfluous XML attributes in newer WiX sources: **[Syntax for guids in WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732761/syntax-for-guids-in-wix/24769965#24769965)** (recommended read - should be quick).

The gist of it is that you can do this:

```
<Component>
  <File Source="..\File.dll" />
</Component>
```

instead of the older, more elaborate:

```
<!-- Sample guid below, do not copy paste -->
<Component Id="File.dll" Guid="{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789ABC}">
  <File Id="File.dll" Name="File.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\File.dll" />
</Component>
```

All the missing attributes will be auto-populated by WiX - making it easier to implement any changes in the compiler and linker that is picked up by your "slimmer source". Should an attribute be needed - for some reason - you will be told to add it by the compiler / linker / documentation.

***Solution?***: Accordingly, please try to remove the whole **`Name attribute`** and see if this solves your problem. I would remove as many other fields as possible as well (should make future migration easier - maybe).